# How can I use goroutine to execute for loop?

Tags: go, goroutine

Suppose I have a slice like:

`stu = [{"id":"001","name":"A"} {"id":"002", "name":"B"}]` and maybe more elements like this. inside of the slice is a long string, I want to use json.unmarshal to parse it.

```
type Student struct {
   Id   string `json:"id"`
   Name string `json:"name"`
}

studentList := make([]Student,len(stu))
for i, st := range stu {
   go func(st string){
      studentList[i], err = getList(st)
      if err != nil {
         return ... //just example
      }
   }(st)
}
//and a function like this
func getList(stu string)(res Student, error){
   var student Student
   err := json.Unmarshal(([]byte)(stu), &student)
   if err != nil {
      return
   }
   return &student,nil
}
```

I got the nil result, so I would say the goroutine is out-of-order to execute, so I don't know if it can use studentList[i] to get value.

Comment: When you use `go` to launch goroutines, there is no "out-of-order". Goroutines run concurrently, in unspecified order, unless you use explicit synchronization.

Comment: What is "the nil result"? Most likely you need a waitgroup to make this use of goroutines correct. Though, the use of goroutines here is probably not useful, and maybe not even applicable to your "real problem" (which remains unclear).

Comment: The result return a <nil>.  it seems i and stu are unchanged in this way.  So I can't assign the result to the slice studentList[i] ?

Comment: checkout what a `sync.WaitGroup` does, it might help you in this usecase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few potential issues with your code:

*Value of `i` is probably not what you expect*

```
for i, st := range stu {
   go func(st string){
      studentList[i], err = getList(st)
      if err != nil {
         return ... //just example
      }
   }(st)
}
```

You kick off a number of goroutines and, within them, reference `i`. The issue is that `i` is likely to have changed between the time you started the goroutine and the time the goroutine references it (the for loop runs concurrently to the goroutines it starts). It is quite possible that the `for` completes before any of the goroutines do meaning that all output will be stored in the last element of `studentList` (they will overwrite each other so you will end up with one value).

A simple solution is to pass `i` into the goroutine function (e.g. `go func(st string, i int){}(st, i)` (this creates a copy). See [this for more info](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables).

*Output of studentList*

You don't say in the question but I suspect you are running `fmt.Println(studentList[1]` (or similar) immediately after the `for` loop completes. As mentioned above it's quite possible that none of the goroutines have completed at that point (or they may of, you don't know). Using a `WaitGroup` is a fairly easy way around this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(len(stu))
for i, st := range stu {
    go func(st string, i int) {
        var err error
        studentList[i], err = getList(st)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(st, i)
}
wg.Wait()
```

I have corrected these issues [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3MSgHeNiCla).

Comment: Hi Brits, just one question about your solution: if an error was returned by the `getList` func call, the code will `panic`. Is the statement `wg.Done()` called in this case? should be better use `defer wg.Done()` as first statement in the func?

Comment: `wg.Done()` is not called if an error occurs but this does not really matter as `panic()` will terminate the application regardless. I generally use `defer wg.Done()` if there are a few execution paths that return.

Answer (score 2):

not because of this

> the goroutine is out-of-order to execute

There are at least two issues here:

you should not use the for loop variable `i` in goroutine.

multiple goroutines read `i`, for loop modify `i`, it's race condition here. to make `i` works as expected, change the code to:

```
for i, st := range stu {
   go func(i int, st string){
      studentList[i], err = getList(st)
      if err != nil {
         return ... //just example
      }
   }(i, st)
}
```

what's more, use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all goroutine.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i, st := range stu {
   wg.Add(1)
   go func(i int, st string){
      defer wg.Done()

      studentList[i], err = getList(st)
      if err != nil {
         return ... //just example
      }
   }(i, st)
}

wg.Wait()
```

P.S.: (WARNING: maybe not always true)
this line `studentList[i], err = getList(st)` ,
although it may not cause data race, but it's somehow not friendly to cpu cache line. better avoid writing code like this.